# Converting Strings to Class Names in c#

Tags: c#, .net

i have the following class:

```
class MyClass{  
{
```

and the following string:

```
string s="MyClass";
```

how can i get the Type of the class using string s as such:

```
Type t = typeof(MyClass); //but i need to use s instead.
```

i have already tried

```
Type type = Type.GetType(s); //the result is null
```

Comment: And what happened when you used `Type.GetType(s)`?

Comment: its my bad, i added the comment after John's post..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

with googeling i've found [this](http://forums.devx.com/showthread.php?t=148278)

> Type type = Type.GetType(fully
> qualified class name string);

from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx):

> typeName:
> The assembly-qualified name of the type to get. See
> AssemblyQualifiedName. If the type is
> in the currently executing assembly or
> in Mscorlib.dll, it is sufficient to
> supply the type name qualified by its
> namespace.
>
> Return Value The type with the
> specified name, if found; otherwise,
> nullNothingnullptra null reference
> (Nothing in Visual Basic).

so, ... i believe it was not found when you get null as the result

[for more info for AssemblyQualifiedName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx)

to get an idea of your fully qualified name just do

```
typeof(MyClass).FullName
typeof(MyClass).AssemblyQualifiedName
```

Comment: This should work for him. The result NULL can be returned if there was no such type in that assembly at all.

Comment: that's excatly what i quoted from msdn :)

Comment: To clarify: The string s must be the fully qualified typename, i.e. something like "MyCompany.MyApplication.MyClass", or if it is in the executing assembly you may only need "MyApplication.MyClass". Just using "MyClass" on its own will not work.

Comment: how can i get the assembly-qualified name of a class?

Comment: from the msdn article: `For example, the fully qualified name for a class might look like this: TopNamespace.SubNameSpace.ContainingClass+NestedClass,MyAssembly` ... i suggest you might read through the article!

Answer (score 1):

GetType should work with the qualified name.  Refer to the [following thread](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/484666-type-gettype-string-not-working) (which includes some insights from Jon Skeet)...

Answer (score 1):

If you are always in the same assembly you can use `Assembly.GetType` so you don;t have to store a string with the assembly name.

```
this.GetType().Assembly.GetType("MyNamespace.MyClass");
```